# I can't get the len command working

Tags: python

```
while True :
Vehicle_Number_PLate = ('Please enter the  vehicles number plate: ')
If len(Vehicle_Number_Plate)>7:
    print ('The number plate is invalid, please try again')
    Vehicle_Number_plate = FALSE
If len(Vehicle_Number_Plate)<7:
    print ('The number plate is invalid, please try again')
```

Please can you help me with this, I'm really stuck and I need help. Much appreciated

Comment: `If` is `if`, `while` needs an indent.

Comment: use input('Please enter the  vehicles number plate: ')

Comment: As an aside, `print` is a great debug tool. Try `print(Vehicle_Number_Plate)` and you'll see the problem.

Comment: Rather than two tests you can use "len(Vehicle_Number_Plate) != 7"

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the comments `If` should be `if`, and `FALSE` should be `False`. To get user input use `input('Please enter the vehicles number plate: ')`. You need proper indentation and your variable doesn't match the variable in the `if`s. I believe something like this is what you are looking for:

```
valid=False
while not valid:
    Vehicle_Number_Plate = input('Please enter the  vehicles number plate: ')
    if len(Vehicle_Number_Plate)!=7:
        print ('The number plate is invalid, please try again')
    else:
        print ('The number plate is valid')
        valid=True
```

Comment: OP also invalidates if less than 7.

Comment: fixed to reflect original question, the `else` is something I assume is wanted